# How to check quickly if a list is a sublist of any list contained in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists. One containing integers and one containing lists of integers.
For example:

```py
a = [1,2,3]
b = [[1,2,5],[1,4,7],[1,2,3,5]]
```

Is there a fast method in Python 3 to check if `a` is a sublist of any of the lists in `b`? My example should return True since `a` is a sublist of the last list in `b`. 
If `b` were `[[1,2,4],[1,4,7],[2,3,5]]`, it should return False.

I know i can transform all lists to sets and check individually, but since i have quite large lists, and want to do this operation often, i was wondering if there is a faster way to do this.
`a` and the lists in `b` contain integers between 0 and 1000, without duplicates, `b` contains hundreds of thousands of those list, with again no duplicates.
Thank you in advance!

So far i have:

```py
def check_sublist(a,b):
   for list in b:
      if set(a) <= set(list):
         return True
   return False
```

Comment: subsequence or sublist? If `b` has `(0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3)` would that be a match for `[1,2,3]`? What if the order is different and `b` has `(3, 2, 1)`?

Comment: sublist not subsequence. Your example would both be a match, but in my case the lists are sorted and no duplicates occur

Comment: What's your working code?

Comment: Did you just say not subsequence and that (0,1,0,2,0,3) matches [1,2,3]?

Comment: If you check [avoid asking question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), you would find question like "I use this method, what do you use? " question should get negative response.

Comment: @Hicomputer You're misrepresenting that.

Comment: Either that code is *not* working or you *do* want to accept subsequences.

Comment: I have updated the question and i hope that clarifies a few things. @Kelly Bundy I meant "not subsequence"because that case does not occur for me

Comment: Does a=[1,3] match b=[[1,2,3]]?

Comment: @Kelly Bundy yes

Comment: So you *do* want subsequences.

Comment: How long are `a` and the lists in `b` typically? And is this a one-time thing, or do you for example want to check multiple different `a`-lists against the same `b`?

Comment: @Kelly Bundy I think since my lists are sorted, all sublists are also subsequences. I was not considering this so far, is that observation something where I could improve on computation times?

Comment: a typically contains around 100 integerss, b tens of thousands of such lists. I want to check many times but b is updated. If the function returns False I want to add a to the list b. And then I test millions of lists like a and if they should be added to b.

Comment: Sublists are also subsequences, but that has nothing to do with your sortedness. And subsequences generally aren't sublists.

Comment: With that extra information about what you're actually doing, this is turning into a quite different question...

Comment: @Kelly Bundy I did not want to ask a question like " hey can someone write me a program that does all of what I want". So I chose the function that is called most often and yields the most potential for optimisation.

Comment: But optimizing this would likely be a waste of time, since there likely are *far* better solutions for what you actually want to do.

Comment: You should check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75409502/16702058), I believe you can use a inverted indexed database

Comment: @KellyBundy ok, I hear you, but I still not get it, can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: @Hicomputer You got that from the page's "asking subjective questions" list. This here is not a subjective thing. What that page means is something like "What's your favorite programming language?". What we have here is a specific task and asking for something faster. Whether something is faster than something else is rather objective, not subjective. And such questions are common (and if done well and interesting, can get quite *positive* responses).

Answer (score 0):

I will try to show main idea of inverted index here. Hope it helps.

for Dataset like this:

```
b = [[1,2,5],[1,4,7],[1,2,3,5]]
```

I think with inverted index, the data structure would look like this

```
         0(Document)  1(Document) 2(Document)
1            +           +            +
2            +                        +
3                                     +
4                        +
5            +                        +
6
7                        +
```

##### for input `a=[1,2,3]`,

`1` is in document 0,1,2

`2` is in document 0,2

`3` is in document 2

so document 2 is what we need(index in list `b`).

##### for input `a=[7]`,

`7` is in document 1

so document 1 is what we need(index in list `b`).

##### for input `a=[10]`,

`10` is not found in any document,

return false

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, that looks quite promising, and i will give that a try!